# AngularJS: using a function call in ng-readonly with an argument dynamic update

Tags: html, angularjs

For some of the fields in my webpage they can alternate between being readonly or not readonly. Currently they all have an ng-readonly attribute with a function call like this:

```
ng-readonly="isReadOnly(field)"
```

The function isReadOnly does some logic to determine whether it will return true/false.

However I am unsure if this is dynamic, eg. at some points in time isReadOnly can return a different boolean for the same field argument.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: This is dynamic. Angular will re-evaluate the `isReadOnly` function each digest cycle